# Infinite SUM Cosine and Sine inside Zeta Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, graphing-functions, riemann-zeta

Can anyone come up with the function that describes these infinite series?:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(n)}{n^s}$$

or

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n^s}.$$

It's basically the zeta function, except the 1 in the numerator is replaced by the $\cos(n) $ and $\sin(n)$. The cosine function starts at $-0.5$ for $s=0$, then crosses the $x$-axis at $s \simeq .898635523$, and has an asymptote for $f(x)=\cos(1)$.

Thank you for your help and interest! Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: What's the inspiration for these series?

Comment: See [Clausen function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function).

Answer (score 4):

For $|z| = 1$ and $Re(s) > 1$, the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) has the series representation :
$$Li_s(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} z^{n}$$
Since $n^{-s}\Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-nx}dx$ you get 
$$\Gamma(s) Li_s(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-nx}dx
= \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n e^{-nx}dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{z^{-1}e^{x}-1}dx$$
For $z \ne 1, |z| = 1$ it converges for $Re(s) > 0$ and it has a nice **analytic continuation, meromorphic on the whole complex plane** with poles of order $1$ at the negative integers, since $\frac{1}{z^{-1}e^{x}-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_z(k) x^k $ is analytic at $x=0$, and
$$Li_s(z)\Gamma(s)-\sum_{k=0}^K \frac{c_z(k)}{s+k} = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{z^{-1}e^{x}-1}-\sum_{k=0}^K c_z(k) x^k 1_{x < 1}\right)dx$$
that converges and is analytic for $Re(s) > -K-1$.

Hence $\displaystyle G(s)=  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(n)}{n^s} = \frac{Li_s(e^i)+Li_s(e^{-i})}{2}$ **is entire,** and you have $G(s) \Gamma(s) \sim G(-k)\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(s+k)} \sim \frac{c_i(k)+c_{-i}(k)}{2(s+k)}$ as $s \to -k$ and 
$$G(-k) =  \frac{(-1)^k k!}{2}\left.\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left[\frac{1}{e^{x+i}-1}+\frac{1}{e^{x-i}-1}\right] \ \right|_{x= 0}$$

Comment: Nice answer. How do you show that the exchange $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-an}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-nx}dx
= \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-(a+x)n}dx$$ is legal ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. both side are absolutely convergent :  $\sum_{n \ge N} |e^{-an}| \int_0^\infty |x^{s-1} e^{-nx}|dx \to 0$ and $\int_0^\infty |x^{s-1} |\sum_{n \ge N} |e^{-(a+x)n} |dx \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$

Comment: Okay thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1952009 Above, started with Re(s) > 1, but what about for values Re(s) < 1, i.e. in the critical strip?

Comment: @VinMilligan I don't see what you mean. Your series are analytic on $Re(s) > 0$ as $\eta(s)$. There is no really a critical strip here, and I provided an expression valid for $Re(s) > -K-1$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation and the different representation of [$\zeta(s)$ in $Re(s) \in (0,1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a faster series for evaluating $Li_s(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n} n^{-s}, |z| = 1, z \ne 1$

then adapt what [I wrote there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988430/faster-convergence-for-the-smaller-values-of-the-riemann-zeta-function/1988958#1988958) about $\eta(s) = -Li_s(-1)$ to get
$$\forall s \in \mathbb{C}, \qquad \qquad  Li_s(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} 
\sum_{k=0}^n  {n \choose k} \frac {z^{k+1}}{(k+1)^s}$$