# Upper bound for $\sum\limits_{k=N}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{1+\epsilon}}$

Tags: inequality, riemann-zeta

Background: I'm trying to evaluate the Rieman Zeta function $$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$$

I do not need a high precision, but I need to somehow estimate the error I'm making by cutting the sum of at some point.

So here my question:

Given a $\epsilon>0$ and an $N \in \mathbb N$ (e.g. $\epsilon < 2$) is there an upper bound for $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}} $$?

Comment: This way you can evaluate $\zeta(s)$ only for $Re(s) > 1$ and it converges very slowly. You should better use that $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}$ valid for $Re(s )> 0$, from which you get [this formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988430/faster-convergence-for-the-smaller-values-of-the-riemann-zeta-function/1988958#1988958) converging much faster and for every $s \ne 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may apply the [integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)
$$
\int_N^\infty f(x)\,dx\le\sum_{n=N}^\infty f(n)\le f(N)+\int_N^\infty f(x)\,dx
$$ with
$$
f(x):=\frac{1}{x^{1+\epsilon}}.
$$

Comment: Oh great, that looks exactly like what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: @flawr You are welcome. One then gets, for $N\ge1$, $\varepsilon>0$,
$$
\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}\right|\le \frac{1}{N^{1+\varepsilon}}+\frac{1}{\varepsilon N^{\varepsilon}}.
$$