# Another method of proving:$\zeta(s)={1\over 1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1\over 2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k{n\choose k}(k+1)^{-s}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

How do we change [elementary way] $$\eta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\over (n+1)^s}$$ into

$$\zeta(s)={1\over 1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1\over 2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k{n\choose k}(k+1)^{-s}$$

My try:

$${1\over 2}+{1\over 2^2}+{1\over2^3}+{1\over2^4}+\cdots=1$$

$${1\over 2^2}+{2\over 2^3}+{3\over2^4}+{4\over2^5}+\cdots=1$$

$${1\over 2^3}+{3\over 2^4}+{6\over2^5}+{10\over2^6}+\cdots=1$$

$${1\over 2^4}+{4\over 2^5}+{10\over2^6}+{20\over2^7}+\cdots=1$$

And so on ...

we expanded the eta function

$$\eta(s)=1-{1\over 2^s}+{1\over3^s}-{1\over4^s}+\cdots$$

$${1\over 1^s}\left({1\over 2}+{1\over 2^2}+{1\over2^3}+{1\over2^4}+\cdots\right)={1\over1^s}$$

$${1\over 2^s}\left({1\over 2^2}+{2\over 2^3}+{3\over2^4}+{4\over2^5}+\cdots\right)={1\over 2^s}$$

$${1\over3^s}\left({1\over 2^3}+{3\over 2^4}+{6\over2^5}+{10\over2^6}+\cdots\right)={1\over 3^s}$$

$${1\over 4^s}\left({1\over 2^4}+{4\over 2^5}+{10\over2^6}+{20\over2^7}+\cdots\right)={1\over 4^s}$$
collected the terms and we have
$$\eta(s)={1\over2}\left(1\over1^s\right)+{1\over2^2}\left({1\over1^s}-{1\over2^s}\right)+{1\over2^3}\left({1\over1^s}-{2\over2^s}+{1\over3^s}\right)+\cdots$$

put in the sum notation

$$\eta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1\over 2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k{n\choose k}(k+1)^{-s}$$

where

$$\zeta(s)={1\over 1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\over (n+1)^s}={1\over 1-2^{1-s}}\eta(s)$$

so we have

$$\zeta(s)={1\over 1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1\over 2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k{n\choose k}(k+1)^{-s}$$

Comment: The [second bullet point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_summation#Examples) is most likely of greater interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be more specific, you just took what is known as either the Euler transform or the [Binomial transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform).  It is basically what you did, but more general.

The [Euler summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_summation) also happens to be basically the same.

$$_{{E_{y}}}\,\sum _{{j=0}}^{\infty }a_{j}:=\sum _{{i=0}}^{\infty }{\frac  {1}{(1+y)^{{i+1}}}}\sum _{{j=0}}^{i}{i \choose j}y^{{j+1}}a_{j}$$

An Euler sum is equal to the original sum if it exists, and is useful for accelerating convergence and sometimes calculations of divergent series.

Comment: Oh, sorry, we have just given the same answer at the same time. (+1) and deleting mine.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Oh, that's ok :D  Great minds think alike as always.

Comment: oh ok, i thought what i did was nonsense. (+1)

Comment: @X-men If its well known and every step seems reasonable and the end result is right... you probably didn't do nonsense.

Comment: take a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988430/faster-convergence-for-the-smaller-values-of-the-riemann-zeta-function/1988958#1988958)